# OpenGL glDrawPixels on dynamic 3D arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, opengl, graphics

How do you draw the following dynamic **3D** array with OpenGL **glDrawPixels()**?
You can find the documentation here: http://opengl.org/documentation/specs/man_pages/hardcopy/GL/html/gl/drawpixels.html

```
float ***array3d;

void InitScreenArray()
{
    int i, j;

    int screenX = scene.camera.vres;
    int screenY = scene.camera.hres;

    array3d = (float ***)malloc(sizeof(float **) * screenX);

    for (i = 0 ;  i < screenX; i++) {
        array3d[i] = (float **)malloc(sizeof(float *) * screenY);

        for (j = 0; j < screenY; j++)
          array3d[i][j] = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * /*Z_SIZE*/ 3);
    }
}
```

I can use only the following header files:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>     

#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
```

Comment: Yes, but it's just a mall part I can't solve. The whole homework will be a ray tracer and this structure stores the screen pixels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uh ... Since you're allocating *each single pixel* with a separate `malloc()`, you will have to draw each pixel with a separate call to `glDrawPixels()`, too. This is (obviously) insane; the idea of bitmapped graphics is that the pixels are stored in an adjacent, compact, format, so that it is quick and fast (*O(1)*) to move from one pixel to another. This looks very confused to me.

A more sensible approach would be to allocate the "3D array" (which is often referred to as a 2D array of pixels, where each pixel happens to consist of a red, green and blue component) with a single call to `malloc()`, like so (in C):

```
float *array3d;
array3d = malloc(scene.camera.hres * scene.camera.vres * 3 * sizeof *array3d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks unwind. I got the same advice on [gamedev.net](http://www.gamedev.net/community/forums/topic.asp?topic_id=513674) so I have implemented the following algorithm:

```
typedef struct
{
    GLfloat R, G, B;
} color_t;

color_t *array1d;

void InitScreenArray()
{   
        long screenX = scene.camera.vres;
    long screenY = scene.camera.hres;
        array1d = (color_t *)malloc(screenX * screenY * sizeof(color_t));
}

void SetScreenColor(int x, int y, float red, float green, float blue)
{
    int screenX = scene.camera.vres;
    int screenY = scene.camera.hres;

    array1d[x + y*screenY].R = red;
    array1d[x + y*screenY].G = green;
    array1d[x + y*screenY].B = blue;
}

void onDisplay( ) 
{
    glClearColor(0.1f, 0.2f, 0.3f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glRasterPos2i(0,0); 
    glDrawPixels(scene.camera.hres, scene.camera.vres, GL_RGB, GL_FLOAT, array1d);

    glFinish();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

My application doesn't work yet (nothing appears on screen), but I think it's my fault and this code will work.

Answer (score 0):

wouldn't you want to use glTexImage2D() instead: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1080545/how-to-display-a-raw-yuv-frame-in-a-cocoa-opengl-program)